# Who are those who have gone astray in (5:105) according Shi'a?

Tags: tafseer, shiism, surat-al-maidah

In verse ([5:105](http://legacy.quran.com/5/105)) Allah says:

> O you who have believed, upon you is [responsibility for] yourselves. **Those who have gone astray will not harm you when you have been guided**. To Allah is you return all together; then He will inform you of what you used to do.

based on Qur'an one could assume that "those who have gone astray" may refer to people who have changed their faith, or done wrong, one could even point or conclude that the people meant here are from among people of the book. The sunni traditions on this verse however seem to reject this last conclusion (see for example in [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/740610)).

I'd like to know the Shi'a interpretation: Who are meant by "Those who have gone astray" in this verse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
               In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

Based on my research, according to Ayatollah Makarem --as a Shia Islam Marja'-Taqlid--, they are including:

> Your ancestors, or friends and relatives of your era

Reference and further information:

- [https://makarem.ir](https://makarem.ir/main.aspx?reader=1&pid=61872&lid=0&mid=19323&catid=0)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about and put in context?